# setworldcoordinates clears the screen of any turtle drawings

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
import math
turtleSize=1
turtle.speed(1)

turtleA=turtle.Turtle()
turtleA.shape("circle")
turtleA.shapesize(turtleSize)

screenSizeX=180
screenSizeY=3
llx=0
turtle.setworldcoordinates(llx,-screenSizeY,screenSizeX,screenSizeY)

for i in range(180):
    turtleA.goto(i,(2*math.sin(0.1*i)))
    screenSizeX=screenSizeX+1
    llx=llx+1
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(llx,-screenSizeY,screenSizeX,screenSizeY)
```

What I am trying to do it create a turtle making a sine function, however the actual turtle will appear as though it remains in place, because every time the turtle moves, the world coordinates will move slightly with it. Think a snake slithering on a TV but its head remains in the center of the screen and the camera is just moving along with it. Whenever I try to set the world coordinate after I've moved the turtle, everything the turtle drew disappears. I realize that this may not be the best solution for the the challenge, however I can't think of one better.

Answer (score 2):

## The Problem

As you would know, turtle by default draws from the coordinate `(0,0)`, and your world by default renders in the rectangle `(-200, -150, 200, 150)` and is of size `400 x 300`.

You are drawing from the default home location `(0 + offset,0)`, and your screen renders to
`(0 + offset, -3, 180 + offset, 3)`.

Therefore, the last point always draws at the middle of the left border, and all the previous drawn points are left behind (pun intended). This is why you don't see the (pretty) graph.

[image]

## The Solution

You want the last point (the circle) to always be drawn at the center.

What you would want is something like this:

```
turtle.setworldcoordinates(
    -screenWidth / 2 + point_positionX,
    -screenHeight / 2 + point_positionY,
    screenWidth / 2 + point_positionX,
    screenHeight / 2 + point_positionY
)
```

Where `point_positionX` and `point_positionY` are the coordinates of the last drawn point.

Let me give you something to build on:

```
'''
Graph Simulation (Limited to sine waves with amplitude 0.5 and frequency pi/180)
'''

import turtle       # For drawing graph
import math         # For calculating positions

# Initialise turtle
turtleSize = 1
turtle.speed(1)

# Initialise the sketcher
graphSketcher = turtle.Turtle()
graphSketcher.shape("circle")
graphSketcher.shapesize(turtleSize)

# Some constants
SCREEN_WIDTH = 180
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 3
AMPLITUDE = 0.5
WAVES_IN_SCREEN = 10
ANGULAR_FREQUENCY = math.pi/180

# Set the correct scale
turtle.setworldcoordinates(-SCREEN_WIDTH/2, -SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)

for time in range(181):
    # Draw the graph
    graphSketcher.goto(
        time,
        AMPLITUDE * math.sin(2 * ANGULAR_FREQUENCY * time * WAVES_IN_SCREEN)
    )
    # move forward in time and space
    # Try commenting this to see the difference!
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(
        -SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + time,
        -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2,
        SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + time,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2
    )
```

You just have to work it out for the y offsets. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I try to set the world coordinate after I've moved the
>   turtle, everything the turtle drew disappears.

The *first* call to `setworldcoordinates()` can be destructive to the current turtle state, so I always recommend you call it as early as possible in your program.  For example:

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(300, 300)
# turtle.mode('world')
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(5)  # make a large cursor
turtle.setheading(90)  # turtle facing upward
turtle.stamp()  # leave a lasting impression

turtle.setworldcoordinates(-150, 150, 150, -150)  # flip coordinates upsidedown

turtle.exitonclick()
```

The call to `setworldcoordinates()` to flip the coordinate system upsidedown will also remove the stamp, and reset the turtle size and direction.  However, if you uncomment the `turtle.mode('world')` call, it will prevent that.

Subsequent calls to `setworldcoordinates()` are not as destructive as seen in @JaideepShekhar's excellent (+1) answer to your question.  I've worked with Jaideep's example code and come up with what I believe is a closer approximation to what you describe:

```
import turtle
import math

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 1.0
AMPLITUDE = 0.25
WAVES_IN_SCREEN = 10
ANGULAR_FREQUENCY = math.pi / WIDTH

turtle.setworldcoordinates(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
turtle.tracer(False)

for time in range(720):
    extent = AMPLITUDE * math.sin(2 * ANGULAR_FREQUENCY * time * WAVES_IN_SCREEN)
    turtle.setposition(time, extent)
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(-WIDTH/2 + time, extent - HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2 + time, extent + HEIGHT/2)
    turtle.update()

turtle.tracer(True)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Note that swapping the order of the `setposition()` and `setworldcoordinates()` calls will have a bad result despite there being no obvious reason not to do so.  This rework has a slight *quiver* in the cursor as the amplitude changes sign -- it's not perfectly stationary as desired.